# Does this sentence sound natural, 'We read to the children from books in the library'?

Tags: usage

If it does, how about paraphrasing the sentence into 'We read books in the library to the children.'?

Comment: It depends on where the children are. If the children are in the library, you would say, "We read books to the children in the library." If the children are not in the library (for example, you are doing a video chat during a pandemic) you would say, "We read books from the library to the children."

Comment: @SarahT That sounds like an answer.

Comment: Also, 'to read _from_ a book' can mean that only selected passages are read out.

Comment: Also, if the books are from the library you can call them library books rather than books in the library.